# Returning strings from external function while preventing memory leaks

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to pass a string of variable length through getaddrinfo function, my code is basically:

```
char *fun(char *ip) {
    struct addrinfo* res;
    int error;

    // resolve the domain name into a list of addresses 
    error = getaddrinfo(ip, NULL, NULL, &res);
    if (error != 0) {   
       if (error == EAI_SYSTEM) {
          perror("getaddrinfo");
       } else {
          fprintf(stderr, "error in getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(error));
       }   
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // go over returned result and do inverse lookup
    char hostname[NI_MAXHOST];
    error = getnameinfo(res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen, hostname, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, 0); 
    if (error != 0) {
       fprintf(stderr, "error in getnameinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(error));
    }

    // here I use a pointer in order to pass the string without gcc complain about passing a local var
    char *visname = strdup(hostname);

    /* if I uncomment the below then string is passed correctly */
    // printf("%s\n", hostname);

    freeaddrinfo(res);
    return visname;
 }

int main() {
    ...
    for (int n=0; n<ips; n++) {
       printf("%s\n", fun(ip[n]) );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now here's the thing:

1. If I use strdup to copy "hostname" to "visname" then I'm pretty sure I need to free visname somehow, however since I'm passing it through return my question is whether freeing it after return (inside "fun" function) is ok?
2. If I print "hostname" or "visname" inside "fun" and then pass it - that also seems to work, though my assumption is it might be due to "undefined behavior"?
3. Since char *visname is a pointer to the local variable "hostname", shouldn't simply: char *visname = hostname work (i.e. return the hostname string)?

### Edit

I'm pretty sure I can pass a string as a parameter to fun function and then return it, but since it's of variable length then that mean I'll need to keep freeing it every time.

So my preference is to somwhow pass the hostname through the function and then I'll handle it inside main...

Comment: 1) no 2) yes 3) no

Comment: Document it, *well*, and let the caller free the memory. That of course means you can not call it like that, just discarding the pointer once it done being used in the `printf` call.

Comment: Another option is to pass in a buffer (and its max-size) as argument to the function and use that buffer, again letting the caller handle it.

Comment: fix your indentation, it is hard to read your code

Answer (score 0):

1. No you need to free it outside the function.
2. You can printf it if you have allocated the memory for it (and have a valid string there) as printf does not change its parameters.
3. No as the the local variable will invalidate on the function exit and you will return the pointer to the non existing (in the non this function scope) object.

   ```
   int main() {
      ...
      char *ptr;
      for (int n=0; n<ips; n++) {
          printf("%s\n", (ptr = fun(ip[n])) );
          free(ptr);
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

After your edit;

```
    int main() {
       ...
       char ptr[MAXHOSTNAMESIZE +1];
       for (int n=0; n<ips; n++) {
           printf("%s\n", (fun(ip[n], ptr)) );
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

or

```
    int main() {
       ...
       char *ptr = malloc(MAXHOSTNAMESIZE +1);
       for (int n=0; n<ips; n++) {
           printf("%s\n", (fun(ip[n], ptr)) );
        }
        free(ptr)
        return 0;
    }

char *fun(char *ip, char *buff) {
    struct addrinfo* res;
    int error;

    ///......
    error = getnameinfo(res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen, buff, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, 0);
    if (error != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error in getnameinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(error));
    }
    //....
    return buff;
}
```

Comment: The options you showed and especially answer number 3 were what I was looking for.
I would love if you could elaborate on answer 1: would declaring and freeing "visname" in main will also free the memory from "visname" in "fun" function?
For reference, I'd like to point out that since I want a char of variable length - that is impossible to implement without freeing it later.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. But I understand it corectly : You cant free memory and use it somewhere else (unless you have copied its content to another allocated location before freeing). It is the same as with the cake :)